# Git: How to get a list of pushed branches to remote master?

Tags: git, git-branch

Maybe I am confusing terms here. Please explain.

I know how to get a list of merged branches on remote master:

```
$git branch -r --merged master
```

But how can I get the list of pushed branches to remote master?

I mean that while being on master branch, after merging, I committed

```
$git push
```

command.

Comment: What do you mean by pushed branches ? Are you referring to all branches in remote ?

Comment: Yes. If I could have list of the ones that I specifically pushed it would have been better.

Comment: Do you mean that you need the list of all remote branches excluding the ones that are only in your local right?

Comment: `But how can I get the list of pushed branches to remote master?`<- what do you mean by `remote master`? You mean branches that you merged to your master branch in your remote?

Comment: I'd like to get an inventory of all the branches I have not only merged but also pushed to remote master.

Comment: Please, clarify what you refer as `remote master`. Are you talking about the master branch in the remote?

Comment: @jweyrich yes I do

Comment: Maybe `git branch -r --merged | grep -q remotes/origin/master` ?

Comment: So this one will give me the merged branches, wouldn't it?

Comment: Updated answer. Actually your original command would have been sufficient to get the required info. If you club it with git fetch.

`git fetch
git branch -r --merged origin/master` this is what you need I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all branches using the following command:

```
git branch -a
```

Then just pipe the output to grep to filter what you want. To show only remote branches, try this:

```
git branch -a | grep "^\s*remotes/"
```

Or simply:

```
git branch -r
```

And for remote merged branches:

```
git branch -r --merged
```

As mentioned by @Krantisinh, it's **important to execute `git fetch` first** in order to guarantee the local infos are up to date.

Comment: What is the difference between your suggestion and the listing of merged as I showed in my question? I'd like to understand please.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please, try updating it.

Comment: In my question I listed a command I used to get the list of all the branches I merged to master. I want to have the list of all the branches I also pushed to master. So I wonder what is the difference between the command I wrote to the one I suggested.

Comment: `git branch -a | grep "^\s*remotes/"` This does not work on windows, would be nice if you could expand your answer to note this.

Answer (score 2):

List of all branches:

```
git branch -a
```

List of all remote branches:

```
git branch -r
```

List of all branches with branch specific info:

```
git branch -a --format="%(refname) | Authored by: %(authorname) | Created Date: %(authordate:short)"
```

This command will give you list of branches on remote that have been merged with master. [git fetch is necessary to ensure git is comparing the latest master.] :

```
git fetch
git branch -r --merged origin/master
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since your answer is the same like @jweyrich but he answer 2 minutes before you I preferred to "accept" his answer instead of yours. I hope you'll understand :)

Comment: hehe.. That should be alright as long as you get your answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still not quite sure how to verify that a local branch (master in specifics) was pushed already to remote... :(